# Specifying a version number and the 'cpuonly' option in YAML for a conda environment config

Tags: conda

My YAML config file for my conda environment looks like this (cut down)

```yml
name: proj36
channels:
  - defaults
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - numpy
  - pandas==0.25.3
  - python==3.6.10
  - pytorch==1.2.0
  - torchvision==0.4.0
```

If I was installing pytorch and torchvision from the command prompt I could specify the cpuonly version like this

```bash
conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 cpuonly -c pytorch
```

How should I add the `cpuonly` option in my YAML config file without losing the version number?

I have tried

```yaml
- pytorch==1.2.0 cpuonly
```

which gives the error

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:  
    - pytorch==1.2.0=cpuonly
```

and

```yaml
- pytorch==1.2.0, cpuonly
```

which gives the error

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:  
    - pytorch[version='1.2.0,cpuonly']
```

What is the correct syntax?

(Bonus points if you can point me at some documentation where I might have worked out what to do.)

Answer (score 1):

Got it, I needed to add the `cpuonly` as another item at the end of the YAML dependencies list.

```yml
name: proj36
channels:
  - defaults
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - numpy
  - pandas==0.25.3
  - python==3.6.10
  - pytorch==1.2.0
  - torchvision==0.4.0
  - cpuonly
```